Two adjustable pulses using basic components
I would like to accomplish the following:
The circuit is off when connected to 12v. A momentary switch is pressed. Nothing happens on the push, but upon release an immediate pulse switches a relay on for 0-1s, then after a delay of 0-1s, switches it on again for 0-2s and then it stays off until the button is pressed again. Basically two adjustable pulses with an adjustable delay in between. I'd like to do this using 555 chips/transistors. No other ICs.
I've worked out a way to do a single adjustable pulse using rc timer, a potentiometer and a transistor and a separate approach based on 555 chips to control the number of equal pulses. Not sure how to execute a way to adjust the pulses and the delay in between them independently. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome! Is an MCU out of the question for you? Even the cheapest and smallest one would do this for you. Is the output signal also 12 V?

What are the relay coil voltage and current specs?

An ATtiny85 mcu will solve your problems for $2. It will take care of button debouncing too.

The power source is 12v, and the relay is 10A. It's not that an MCU is out of the question, it's that it won't help me understand how the basic components are used.

With transistors opened ring counter:
P1, P2, P3 sets the timing. Or change capacitors according needs.
Q6 and Q7 is an OR gate, so both pulses switch the relay On.

Or with better OR gate that neglect a collectors roundings, making a relay pulses sharp:

Edit: (respond to comments)
The pots cannot be turned all the way. The voltage between viper and Gnd has to be about 2 or 3V at least otherwise the Q345 will not stay saturated. You can place a 470ohm resistors below the pots (in series with pots) to cut their range.
For proper power-up initialization to avoid short relay click you need to keep Q345 saturated/conducted (collectors at 0V) immediatelly after power is applied. More easy is to parallel Q345 with additional transistors and keep them conducting for a first second after power-up. Use a RC derivative for one second timing:

The initial glitch (relay click) can by avoided also by rising the Vcc of logic circuitry slowly, like 0-12V in 100ms. You can use a PNP on Vcc side and charge the C_filter(like 1mF) for logic circuitry in 100ms ramp.
The button and schmitt should work with any signal ~100mA transistors with beta 100-300. The D1 should have a bit less zener voltage than D2. The R6 sets the hysteresis, you can try lower it to 68k or 47k to increase the hysteresis (inactive) zone.
Edit2:
Try to replace schmitt trigger to one that doesn’t contain an inverter:

Regarding capacitor for initial pulse to transistors parallel to Q345 it was meant 470uF.

This is exactly how i was trying to approach this in my head but couldn't execute on it. I really like this solution

I went ahead and put this together and on power up im getting a single relay click. Also if the potentiometer for either pulse is turned all the way up, the relay gets switched on indefinitely. While it's on, the button, on release, turns it off and back back on. Did i introduce this behavior by substituting the transistors and the zener diodes, or is something else going on. They're pretty close in specs, (within 1 volt) but i wanted to see if you might be getting the same behavior in the software. Ty

Thank you for the response. I went ahead and added transistors in parallel with q345, as shown in the drawing, however, the relay still gets turned on. I wasn't sure whether the drawing said 470mF or nF, but i tried them both and every value in between. As the capacitance decreases, the click gets shorter, but instead of going away entirely, what happens is, it turns into a studder click, before a long click once again. Idk if that makes sense. For the pnp transistor suggestion, where do i place the 1mF filter capacitor? And would gate go to ground through a resistor (1k?) to be pulled low? Ty

That got the click to go away, but without the Inverter, the sequence would initiate on button press instead of release. Omitting the Schmitt trigger altogether got it to work the way i wanted. I added the button between positive and the first 1mF capacitor, with a1k resistor to ground. Thanks for all the updates. If you don't mind answering one more question, what's the reason you used different transistors for the OR gate? Is it something to do with the gain? I noticed using some transistors didn't work, im just not sure why. Some either always stay on, and others don't turn on at all.

Solving this task only using NE555 and discrete components escalated a bit. I use a chain of 3 timers here, where R2, R4 and R6 define the timing of the first on period, the pause and the second on period. They could be implemented using potentiometers in series with a fixed minimum resistor of around 1 kΩ to protect the discharge outputs. A time of true zero cannot be reached.
The discharge current of the timing capacitors C1 and C2 enables a base current in Q1 and Q2, which produces the negative going trigger edge for the next timer. The capacitor charge current flows through D3 and D4. This transistor stages prohibit a false trigger at power on, where the timer outputs also are low and would meet the trigger condition of the next timer.
The peak base current of Q1 and Q2 is relative high, but short. If this is an issue, a series resistor of 100 Ω in the discharge path (pin 7) can be added.
The outputs of timer 1 and 3 are combined in a wired OR with D1 and D5 to turn the relay on. This could as well be a transistor or FET.
All 3 timer outputs are combined via D6, D7 and D8 to create a trigger lock signal for Q4, which disables charging C4 while the sequence is running.
Your start button, here SW1, charges C4, but only if Q4 is conducting. If the button stops conducting, the stored charge in C4 enables a base current in Q3 via R7, which starts the first timer.
I added R10 to compensate leakage current in Q4 while it is off, and C5 to hold the lock signal active during take over from one active timer output to the next.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This is exactly what i was looking for, you even took care of a false trigger at power on, thank you so much!

I forgot to mention: If you run this from 12 V, a higher value for R8 (1.2 kohm) is required to avoid reverse BE breakdown in Q3 while Q4 is off. The voltage divider R8/R7 should limit the voltage at C4 to around 5 V. This is not a problem for Q1 and Q2, where the diodes catch this.

Thanks, i should have mentioned that it's a 12v circuit, so that's helpful

Here's an idea that avoids the need to trigger monostables in sequence. Instead I trigger three independent timers with the same signal, which I'll explain in a moment. First you need a short trigger pulse that occurs on switch release:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Now trigger three independent timers with that TRIG signal. The pulse duration of each is slightly longer than the last, say 1s, 2s and 3s respectively:

simulate this circuit
I've disabled all the timer ICs for a short duration at power-on, with R5 and C2, to prevent a false trigger. Here's an example of the outputs of each timer, in response to a short trigger pulse (blue). I've separated them vertically to be able to distinguish them, so ignore the vertical scale:

The sequence of timer outputs is as follows, where F is the desired output state:



A
B
C
F




0
0
0
0


1
1
1
1


0
1
1
0


0
0
1
1


0
0
0
0



This is \$F=C\cdot (A \oplus B)\$, which can be implemented with some diodes and transistor Q2 below. Q3 is just to drive the relay coil:

simulate this circuit

I believe this to be robust, because it does not rely on one timer to trigger the next, which is always a bit hit-and-miss. However, there is the possibility that the user could press the button in the middle of a cycle, which would re-trigger the earlier timers. Since C is high throughout, I'm sure there's a way use C to disable the switch, but I haven't given that any thought.

The overall sequence of the pulses so short that pressing a button in the middle of the cycle     probably won't be an issue. I will try this out and find out for sure though. Thank you for the answer

How do i incorporate this approach where the pulse durations can be adjusted independently of each other using 10k potentiometers? I tried to replace the 10/22/33k resistors with potentiometers and it seems to only work if each trigger signal is longer than the one before. For example, if i set the first pulse to be longer than the time duration before the second pulse, or if the first pulse is longer than the second, i end up with a single pulse. Is this just an inherent property of this approach with a common trigger for three separate timers not triggered by one another? Ty

@nocandopdx The three timers are entirely independent, and this design does indeed require each to be slightly longer than the one before. That is, as you noted, an inherent property of this approach. You can make a timing resistance adjustable, while  imposing a lower limit, by placing a fixed resistance in series with a variable one. For instance, 5kΩ fixed in series with 10kΩ variable gives you an adjustable resistance between 5kΩ and 15kΩ.

I have the same basic approach as Jens, but unless I'm missing something his seems overly complex.  Because a 555 takes a negative edge as a trigger, cascading 555's falls out naturally.  The circuit is naturally monotonic without common-base level shifters or steering diodes.
The TS doesn't say anything about the button being pressed in the middle of the sequence.  If this is an issue, it can be fixed with a 4th 555 acting as a Set-Reset flipflop.
Here is a first-pass at a schematic.  Not counting the 555's, switch, or relay, 45 component pins as opposed to 60.  Click on the schematic for a larger image.

R1-C1 - Power-on Reset (POR) timer.  Note that the reset period is much shorter than one R1-C1 time constant because the worst-case threshold voltage for the Reset input is only 0.4 V.  For a 12 V circuit, that comes out to around 0.053 x R1 x C1.  The POR effective time constant must be longer than that of the interstage differentiators R4-C4 and R6-C6.  For a 12 V system, that works out to around 19x.  100k / 2.2 uF is around 22x, which is a nice operating margin.
R2-C2-R8 - Switch differentiator.  R8 pulls the switch output low when the switch opens.  It is much less than R2, and pulls C2 low enough to trigger U1.
R3-R5-R7 / C3-C5-C7 - These are the three output pulse period components.  The component values can be adjusted per the 555 datasheet equation.
R9-R10-R11 - These set the minimum pulse times.  They also protect the 555 Discharge transistor from a dangerous overcurrent if R3-R5-R7 are turned down to 0 ohms.
R4-R6-C4-C6 - These form differentiators to turn the trailing edge of a 555 output pulse into a short trigger pulse for the next 555.
D1 and D2 combine the first and third 555 outputs into the relay.  If the relay coil current is above 100 mA (for a biploar 555), better to add a driver transistor.  With CMOS 555's you must add a driver transistor, as the output is rated for only 10 mA sourcing.
Update:
C8-C9-C10 are power supply decoupling capacitors for the three ICs.  The internal functioning of most ICs assumes a zero ohm impedance voltage source.  Wiring and pc board traces have both resistance and inductance, and to the chip these appear in series between the IC and a perfect power source.
The voltage across these external impedances varies with the signal characteristics (and hence the current) through the IC.  This causes the voltage at the IC pin to vary with signal current, and this can cause a fluctuation in the input stage currents, voltages, gain, etc.  Not everything in every chip all the time, but enough things in enough chips to make decoupling an industry standard.
Analog ICs are generally more sensitive to this than digital ones, and audio power amp ICs such as the LM386 or TDA2002 are particularly grouchy.
The caps also act as a noise filter, reducing the effects of power supply noise and system noise induced by other components on the same power rails.

I already know this is going to be a stupid question, but what is C8, C9 and C10 in the top right?

See the update . . .
